# Overloading template class with template function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

C++ allows to use class and function with the same name in one namespace:

```
struct S {};
void S() {}
```

In this case pure name `S` means function `S`. To use struct instead you need to explicitly add `struct` before name.

It's also possible to make function template and still use both of them:

```
template <class T>
void S() {}

struct S {};
```

But using template struct is forbidden

```
void S() {}

template <class T>
struct S {};
```

and [gives error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qNocmcoPjjoAXYd6) like this:

> ```
> error: redefinition of 'S' as different kind of symbol
> ```

What is the reason for this? Why not to allow use template struct here? Is there any situation where using explicit keyword `struct` before `S` (like for non-template version) could not solve name collision if it was allowed? Maybe there is proposal exist?

Comment: is there any situation where having a type and a function with the same name is not confusing? What would be the benefits?

Comment: Guess:a bad idea inherited from C for compat reasons? That would explain things well but I don't know if it's true.

Comment: @tobi303 one known example is [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) function. You need to remember just one name :)

Comment: isnt that a c function? I dont know C, but I wouldnt know any reason in c++ to have a function and type with same name

Comment: @tobi303 of course. But c++ is mostly compatible with c code. I also see no reason to forbid that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> C++ allows to use class and function with the same name in one namespace.
>
> ```
>    struct S {};
>    void S() {}
> ```

Normally when you declare `struct S`, you can refer to the type in two ways: as `S` and as `struct S`. But that's only until you declare something else named `S`, for example, a function. When you do that, the name of the type is not `S` any more. It's `struct S` only. The name `S` is reserved for the function.

This is done for compatibility with C. C code uses this device frequently. Unlike C++, C places struct and union tags in a different name space from normal identifiers, and `struct S` cannot be referred to as simply `S`.

So C++, in order to be able to compile C code that uses this device, makes an exception for struct tags that are reused as a different kind of identifier.

As `class` is nearly synonymous with `struct`, this is done for the `class` keyword too.

But C has no templates and there's no need to provide backward compatibility for them, so no such exception for class templates is made.

Comment: But what we are winning by forbidding such overloading?

Comment: @alexolut We are winning peace of mind. Less gratuitous complexity to worry about is always good. By the way this is not overloading.

Comment: We could write template make-functions named as type. E.g. `struct S<T> S(T t) { return struct S<T>(t); }` instead of `makeS` function. In C++17 same call, i.e. `S(t)` without using explicit type is allowed via template deduction guide only.

Comment: BTW why second case is allowed (template function and non-template struct)?

Comment: But then we would have to write `struct S<T>` each time we want to use a type.

Comment: It's not that. It's a "struct and one other thing". Could be a function or a function template or a variable, doesn't matter.

Comment: Anyway, "why C++ doesn't have my favourite feature" is a fruitless discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I think function template name is allowed to be the same as something else to allow overloading, while class template name is explicitly disallowed to match something else according to

> 14 Templates [temp]
>
> 5. A class template shall not have the same name as any other template, class, function, variable, enumeration, enumerator, namespace, or type in the same scope (3.3), except as specified in (14.5.5).

[update] the rest of this piece makes me think that the case with function template not causing the same error violates the standard requirements:

> Except that a function template can be overloaded either by non-template functions (8.3.5) with the same name or by other function templates with the same name (14.8.3), **a template name declared in namespace scope or in class
> scope shall be unique in that scope**.

and VS / clang / gcc seem to disagree on it [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/7owRin)

Comment: The question is "why", not "what".

Comment: @n.m. Agree. I would like to rephrase the question of the OT into: who can post a piece of code that would end up in bitter misery if this were allowed.

Comment: @n.m. my guess is that same names is only allowed for compatibility with c. And with templates there is no reason to care about backwards compatibility

Comment: BTW switching order of definition makes CL compiler happy.